# Copy half of the rows of the .csv file and save in .xlsx (in Python, Pandas or other module)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, xlsx

I need to convert .csv file to .xlsx file in Python, size of the file is 446mb, but if I am using next code:

```
import pandas as pd

read_file = pd.read_csv(r'D:\Назар\Бізнес\Реалізація\External_trade_data_01.2021-12.2021_UK.csv')
read_file.to_excel(r'D:\Назар\Бізнес\Реалізація\test.xlsx', index=None, header=True)
```

The result is:

```
ValueError: This sheet is too large! Your sheet size is: 2 006 894, 28 Max sheet size is: 1 048 576, 16384
```

**How I can copy a header and the first 1 003 447 lines of the .csv file and save in .xlsx file (or csv, then I will convert the whole file to .xlsx), than copy next 1 003 447 lines of the .csv file and save to another .xlsx file.**

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
size_file = read_file.shape[0]
read_file1 = read_file.iloc[:int(size_file/2), :]
read_file2 = read_file.iloc[int(size_file/2):, :]
read_file1.to_excel(r'D:\Назар\Бізнес\Реалізація\test1.xlsx', index=None, header=True)
read_file2.to_excel(r'D:\Назар\Бізнес\Реалізація\test2.xlsx', index=None, header=True)
```

Comment: Edited the code, my bad, mistook rows for columns. try this?

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!
I have modified the code a little, because  an error appears.
In the version below everything is working.
read_file1 = read_file.iloc[0:int(size_file/2), :]
read_file2 = read_file.iloc[int(size_file/2): int(size_file), :]

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out :D

Answer (score 0):

You can split the csv dataframe into multiple dataframes of smaller size (chunks of 500,000 rows for example) using `pandas`. Then, you can use `to_excel` to convert them.

```
chunksize = 500000
source_path = r'D:\Назар\Бізнес\Реалізація\External_trade_data_01.2021-12.2021_UK.csv'
for i,chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv(source_path, chunksize=500000, dtype=dtypes)):
    chunk.to_excel('split_csv/chunk{}.xls'.format(i), index=None, header=True)
```

You can also check `to_excel()` options if you can export them to one file with multiple sheets instead of having multiple files.

Comment: When I used this code ModuleNotFoundError appeared, than I have changed .xls to .csv FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'split_csv/chunk0.csv' appear. But I have already solved this question, thank you for the answer.

Comment: just create a folder named `split_csv` to prevent the error. You can also use  `chunk.to_excel(f"chunk{i}.xls", index=None, header=True)` to create the xls file in the same folder as the script file.